# Altium PCB Footprint Component Size Does Not Interpret Text Properly

Tags: pcb, altium

I have just updated from Altium 17 to Altium 18 and I am seeing a strange behavior where the special string text overrides the the actual size of the text.

This special string text size is being interpreted as part of the entire component, and therefore I am getting DRC errors. 
[image: image of part select with larger than expected highlighting]

I have attached in image that shows the the designator (U29) is completely inside the part, but when the part is selected, Altium interprets the size of the component with the special string ('.Designator') and is therefore much larger than it needs to be.

I had this issue in version 17 as well, but I don't remember how to change that setting.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using

.Designator

instead of

'.Designator'

as the string created the appropriate bounding box.